# Windows XP Embedded Standard service pack 3 (SP3)

Tags: windows-update, service-pack, windows-xp-embedded

I looking for service pack 3 (SP3) for Windows XP Embedded Standard version.
I found nothing on official Microsoft links.

Comment: Are you aware that SP3 is not a copy of XP, it's just a collection of patches?

Comment: @fixer1234 : Yes, I looking for the official SP3 collection package for Windows Embedded Standard.

Comment: Did you try updating the machine by running Microsoft Update on the device (on the Tools menu of Internet Explorer)?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, XP is so far out of support that if you run Microsoft Update, you get a message, "Are you kidding?"  :-)

Comment: LOL. I think you actually get that as soon as you launch IE 6. @fixer1234

Answer (score 1):

There is no Service Pack 3 for Windows XP Embedded.

Instead you have to use Windows Embedded 2009.
This is based on Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 und is the successor of Windows XP Embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP Service Pack 3 Embedded can not be openly downloaded online anymore from credible sources. This is partly because it's over 10 years old, and microsoft have ended it's support. XP Service Pack 3 Embedded was also designed to be deplyed by OEM's, so your best chance of acquiring this is to contact your system manufacturer. (Dell, HP, Toshiba, etc..).

The only one that i can find is Service Pack 3 Embedded for Point of Service, which is a different operating system.